# How to start equation environment inside a custom environment?

Tags: equations, environments

Definition of env

```
\newenvironment{env}{
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
\obeylines}
```

When I try to insert a equation it gives me an error.

```
\begin{env}
\begin{equation*}
    \sin{x}
\end{equation*}
\end{env}
```

! Missing $ inserted.
 
                $
l.68     \begin{equation*}

? 
! Display math should end with $$.
 
                   ^^M
l.68     \begin{equation*}

? 
! Missing $ inserted.
 
                $
l.69         \sin
                 {dwa}
? 
! Missing $ inserted.
 
                $
l.69         \sin{dwa}

?

! LaTeX Error: Bad math environment delimiter.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H   for immediate help.
 ...

l.70     \end{equation*}

? 
! Missing $ inserted.
 
                $
l.70     \end{equation*}

? 
! Display math should end with $$.
 
                   \endgroup 
l.70     \end{equation*}

?

If I begin{equtation} outside of the env environment it doesn't give me and error. If I am unable to use env what can I do to achieve the same result?

edit

```
1.1    Definitions
reward = r_t at timestep t 
behaviour policy =π=P(a|s)
observation = s 
set of legal game actions =A={1,...,K}
action = a
optimal action-value function = ~~
```

I'm not writing sentences therefore I need to `\linebreak`.

Comment: Perhaps some additional context would help here. What is `env` supposed to do in terms of your output? Why not just use `equation*` as-is *outside* of `env`?

Comment: the environment definition is unrelated to the error you would get the same error if you just had `\obeylines` before the equation in the main document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\obeylines` makes every line an end of paragraph and you can not end a paragraph in math mode, what would you want `\obeylines` to do in display math?

The error is unrelated to the `env` environment, you get the same error from

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\obeylines
\begin{equation*}
    \sin{x}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

You could remove the `\obeylines` (and add back the missing end environment code)

```
\newenvironment{env}{
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
}
{}
```

But display math should never be at the start of the paragraph (TeX adds a spurious blank initial line in that case) so this environment could not be used in many contexts.

Comment: If i can't use `\obeylines` should I just use `\\ ` for the entire document?

Comment: @Neptune you haven't said what you are trying to do so I can't say. It is _incredibly rare_ to use either construct. Automatic linebreaking is one of the most important and distinctive functions of a typesetting system and you are asking whether to disable it with `\obeylines` or `\\ ` unless you are typesetting poetry and the line breaks are part of the creative input and must be set manually, why do you want to do this at all?

Comment: I'm not writing sentences. I'm enumerating through definitions and equations so I think I need to `\linebreak`.

Comment: @Neptune I see no reason why you would use `\linebreak`, each definition would normally be a paragraph so you just need a blank line, let tex do the linebreaking if the text of a definition is longer than a line, But as you have shown no example document it is hard to say.